# CakePHP-2.0: difference between using public and var

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

CakePHP-2.0 has this=>

```
// Even in your cakephp 2.1.x we have this format
    <?php
    class PostsController extends AppController {
        public $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
        public $name = 'Posts';

        public function index() {
            $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
        }
    }
    ?>
```

CakePHP-1.3.10 had this=>

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {
    var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
    var $name = 'Posts';

    function index() {
        $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }
}
?>
```

What's the difference between using public and using var ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var` is a deprecated [visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) keyword that is functionally equal to `public`.

From the docs:

> Note: The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the var keyword is still supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the public keyword). In PHP 5 before 5.1.3, its usage would generate an E_STRICT warning.

As it's been replaced by the keyword `public`, the new cake is following the new standard.  See working example [here](http://codepad.org/f5Wg2Dtf).

Comment: But i still see var is used in book.cakephp.org, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html

Comment: @guru heh... yeah, the Book isn't always 100% up to date.  Luckily, CakePHP is a collaborative project, and so is the Book!! That means you can log in and edit it to correct such mistakes.  This is a great way to contribute to a project like this, especially since it requires very little time (you can do one edit and stop, if you like) and doesn't require as much technical expertise.

In the name of FOSS, I hereby task you with changing `var` to `public` in the cake book.  The power is yours! :)

Answer (score 3):

"var" existed prior to PHP5 which introduced visibility to objects. Although it still is technically valid, you should avoid it's use and use proper visibility keywords.

To answer your question, they are identical in functionality. However, "var" is deprecated and will go away soon.